# How do I calculate resistor values for a second-order bandpass filter to achieve unity gain at 1 kHz?

Tags: bandwidth, band-pass

The bandpass needs to have a bandwidth of 250 Hz with a centre frequency of 1 kHz.
The values I've calculated so far are R1 = 1000 Ω, R2 = 1000 Ω, C1 = 140 nF, and C2 = 180 nF.

I calculated these using f1 = 1/2πR1C1 and f2 = 1/2πR2C2. I'm not sure if these are completely correct. I am now trying to work out R3 and R4 to give unity gain at 1 kHz.
Any help would be great.

[image]

[image: Circuit diagram]

[image]

Comment: Your fractional bandwidth is 0.25. You'd be a lot better off with a 2nd order active filter rather than combining an HP and an LP which only starts to make sense for fractional bandwidths 3 or 4 times that value. So is this homework? Or?

Comment: @periblepsis Hi yea it says Design a second-order active band-pass two-pole filter, with a noninverting amplifier, using an LM741 integrated circuit and suitable components,
in order to meet the following characteristics:
F0 = 1 kHz, unity gain.
Bandwidth = 250 Hz, is this not a second order filter?

Comment: Sounds like a Sallen-Key or multi-feedback would be fine, then. Are you familiar with them? Or are you only comfortable with the layout you have there? Do you know how to solve the 2nd order transfer function, also?

Comment: Some last questions. You need to specify what the attenuation is at the lower and upper frequencies of your bandpass range. One might assume -3 dB. But that would be an assumption. You need to say what you want there. Do you know how to calculate the lower and upper frequencies from the bandpass number and the center frequency?

Comment: @periblepsis yes I think -3dB is the idea, I can calculate my upper and lower frequencies i think they are 1125 and 850Hz? do you know if there is anywhere that explains how to calculate my resistor and capacitor values for a sallen key configuration?

Comment: There are several bandpass configurations discussed in the Sallen-Key paper. But for this narrow of a bandpass, Sallen-Key is usually not selected. (It can be done, though.) In any case, TI has [this paper](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa024b/sloa024b.pdf?ts=1676792328533&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) that covers the topic pretty well. Is it too "mathy" for you to handle?

Comment: @periblepsis no that looks great thanks, is there a different configuration you would recommend?

Comment: The multifeedback is inverting. So that's excluded. (Sorry about that. Forgot.) Sallen-Key has some inverting and non-inverting topologies. But unfortunately Sallen-Key isn't given much support on the web for non-inverting band-pass.

Comment: @periblepsis Ive designed a sellen key now that I've put in the post, its giving the right resonant frequency and bandwidth but its giving me 20.8dBs of gain at the resonant frequency, do you know how I could make it unity gain?

Comment: Not immediately, though obviously you could add a divider on the output for a divide-by-11. You have the exact right ***shape*** for your goals. By this, I mean that you should be targeting about \$Q=3.99\$ or so. And you do that. I don't know where you got your values, but they are nail-on in terms of the right shape!! If you mess with the existing gain divider tied to the (-) input, you will *also* mess with the shape. So that's not going to help you. But a 10k/1k divider at the output would bring it down to where you want (within resistor tolerances.)

Comment: Have you tried adding the output divider? Also, how exactly did you get those part values? They produce \$Q=4\$ which is very close. But that had to be computed somewhere. I'm impressed with the results. Did you do it yourself? Or use a program?

Comment: @periblepsis I found a website that explained the configuration and how to work out some of the values to get the right Q, I've added it in to the post, I'm not really sure how to add in the output divider though, I put to resistors in series but it completely changed the look of my filter, I might have done it wrong

Comment: Okay. I'll write something up. It's great you found a site to help out. And the divider is pretty easy -- just start with your original circuit and then create a resistor divider pair over on the side away from your circuit. Ground one end of it (the loose end of the 1k.) Tie the loose end of the 10k back to your output. Then plot the output of the middle of the divider.

Answer (score 1):

You have already specified the mid-band gain, the bandwidth, and the center frequency. So:

### Step 1 -- Compute the corner frequencies.

You know \$f_{_\text{H}}-f_{_\text{L}}=250\:\text{Hz}\$ and that \$f_{_0}=\sqrt{f_{_\text{H}}\,\cdot\,f_{_\text{L}}}=1\:\text{kHz}\$. This solves out as \$f_{_\text{L}}\approx 882.78\:\text{Hz}\$ and  \$f_{_\text{H}}\approx 1132.78\:\text{Hz}\$.

### Step 2 -- Compute filter shape \$Q\$

Ignoring gain and ignoring \$f_{_0}\$ for now, find \$Q\$ where:

$$10^{^\frac{-3}{20}}=\left.\middle|\frac{j\frac1{Q}\frac{882.78\:\text{Hz}}{1\:\text{kHz}}}{1-\left(\frac{882.78\:\text{Hz}}{1\:\text{kHz}}\right)^2+j\frac1{Q}\frac{882.78\:\text{Hz}}{1\:\text{kHz}}}\middle|\right.$$

This works out to \$Q\approx 3.99051338\$.

Note that your own solution you found uses \$Q=4\$. Very close.

### Step 3 -- Analyze the chosen topology

I'll draw out the topology you found:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnnrd4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From that, there are a number of simultaneous KCL equations to solve. I won't bother detailing those here. But assuming that \$C_1=C_2\$ and that \$2 R_1=R_2=2R_3\$ then the gain works out to \$K=\frac{1+\frac{R_4}{R_5}}{2-\frac{R_4}{R_5}}\$.

In the above case, \$K=11\$. And that's the result you got.

Also, the shape is \$Q=\frac{1}{2-\frac{R_4}{R_5}}\$. And in your design case this is \$Q=4\$.

But take careful note here. Observe that both \$Q\$ and also \$K\$ are influenced by the same resistor ratio. So if you try to change the gain, you will also change the shape. They cannot be changed independently from each other.

The full analysis of the above is:

$$\begin{align*}
\omega_{_0}&=\sqrt{\frac{R_1+R_3}{R_1\,\cdot\,R_2\,\cdot\,R_3\,\cdot\,C_1\,\cdot\,C_2}}
\\\\
Q&=\frac{\sqrt{R_1\,\cdot\,R_2\,\cdot\,R_3\,\cdot\,C_1\,\cdot\,C_2\cdot \left(R_1+R_3\right)}}{R_1\,\cdot\,R_3\,\cdot\,C_1-\left(R_1\,\cdot\,R_2\cdot\frac{R_4}{R_5}-R_1\,\cdot\,R_3-R_2\,\cdot\,R_3\right)\cdot C_2}
\\\\
K&=\frac{R_2\,\cdot\,R_3\cdot \left(1+\frac{R_4}{R_5}\right)}{R_1\,\cdot\,R_3\cdot\left(1+\frac{C_1}{C_2}\right)-R_1\,\cdot\,R_2\cdot\frac{R_4}{R_5}+R_2\,\cdot\,R_3}
\end{align*}$$

In your circuit, there are some simplifications. Such as \$C_1=C_2\$ and that \$R_1=R_3\$. These details greatly simplify the above general solutions.

But the point here is that you have to analyze your topology and then, taking into account your required \$Q\$ and \$\omega_{_0}\$, you can then consider various ideas that simplify the analysis and help you narrow down the options.

Since you know what you want for all three of the above, you have three equations. But too many unknowns. Making choices like \$C_1=C_2\$ helps reduce the unknowns. Also, note that \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ are not independent, above. Only their ratio is independent. So that's one less unknown. Nice. So with only \$C_1=C_2\$, you have three resistors, one resistor ratio, and one capacitor value to work out.

That's five. Still too many. But its better.

You already know that with certain other assignments, you are still in trouble as the gain is too high. So you might explore the last equation and see where that takes you.

For example, just to prove a point, if you keep \$2 R_1=R_2=2R_3\$ then the last equation for \$K=1\$ solves out as \$\frac{R_4}{R_5}=\frac12\$. That can then be plugged into the equation for \$Q\$ to find that \$Q=\frac23\$. So that proves there's no way to get \$K=1\$ and \$Q=4\$ if you keep the rule that \$2 R_1=R_2=2R_3\$.

By playing around a bit with the last two equations and the values you want there, you will find that \$R_3\lt\frac1{10}R_1\$ (actually less than 9.696%.) Otherwise the results go *imaginary* on you.

I'd just take what you have and do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFbkfz.png)</sup>

For an assignment, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you like the odd shape of the freqwuency response then you can simply put a 2-resistors voltage divider at the output of the opamp.

Here are the very gradual slopes of the opamp with less gain:
[image: simple]

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Sallen-Key topology** (see step 3, contribution from periblepsis) you can meet your bandpass specification using two equal gain-determining resistors R4=R5.

This results in a an **closed-loop gain Acl=2**.

From the known transfer function we can derive the following set of formulas (notataion as in the above mentioned step 3):

**R1=R; R3=R/k3; R2=k2*R; and C1=C2=C.**

Using these abbreviations we get from the transfer function):

**R1=R=2Q/(Ao * wo * C);  k3=1+(2/k2)-(2/Ao) ; k2=(1+k3)(Ao/2Q)²**

**Example**: **Ao=1** (as required); **C=1µF** ; **Q=fo/B=1000/250=4**

**R=R1=1.27kOhm; R3=R1/[2*SQRT(8)-1] ; R2=R1/SQRT(8);
R4=R5 (kOhm range).**